# web2py is not starting with python 3.0/3.1

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, web2py

I am trying to run a web2py application. Using python2.7 it is running fine. 
But I want to use python higher version. When I try with python3.0 or 3.1, am getting an error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/vhosts/astrozon/web2py/web2py.py", line 18, in <module>
    import gluon.widget
  File "/var/www/vhosts/astrozon/web2py/gluon/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from globals import current
ImportError: No module named globals
```

I have checked, the module gobals is present in the same folder. and python2.7 is able to import that module but not for 3.0 or 3.1.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

web2py is not compatible with Python 3, and there are no plans to make it so, as that would break its promise to maintain backward compatibility. There have been a couple of experimental attempts at Python 3 forks, but I do not believe they have been maintained. Work has started on a web3py (not the official name) that will be Python 3 compatible, but that is a completely new framework and still in the early stages of development (there is a plan to include a compatibility layer allowing web2py applications to run under it).